# Que método usar para não mostrar os dados do json na página php que serve de requisição para app android

Tags: php, android, json, web-service, segurança

Boa noite, eu tenho um app android e estou usando esse código php para a requisição de um json e queria que não aparecesse os dados quando alguém usasse a url, porque assim pode ver as informações de saida do select

Como eu poderia fazer para não mostrar e conseguir fazer a requisição dos dados no app?

```
<?php

// APK WebService CRUD

ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');

require_once('config.inc.php');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `contato`';

$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

$statement->execute();

if($statement->rowCount()) {
  $row_all = $statement->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  header('Content-type: application/json');

  echo json_encode($row_all);

} elseif (!$statement->rowCount()) {
  echo "sem linhas";
}

?>
```

Saída:

```
[{"id":"6","nome":"micael","email":"mica@b"},{"id":"7","nome":"agusto","email":"a@b"},{"id":"8","nome":"alma","email":"c@hotmail"}]
```

desde de já obrigado

Comment: Você deveria então usar alguma forma de autenticação, de modo que apenas usuários autenticados pudessem ter algum resultado a partir da consulta ao web-service. Não conheço outro método que não seja gambiarra ou burlável.

Comment: Como ja disse o Jefferson, não tem como, pelo menos não sem criptografia ou algum método de autenticação pra acessar o webservice. Ou, em ultimo caso, se for pra um serviço em locais especificos com máquinas especificas, podes autorizar apenas determinadas origens a efetuar a solicitação para receber o json.

Comment: Você pode até dificultar, mas em todos os casos terá acessar o conteúdo fora do aplicativo. Além disso, você pode, nos termos de uso, declarar que não se pode acessar esses conteúdos fora do aplicativo, "impendido" que usem tal API fora dela, isso é uma questão legal, não de programação. Em geral, isso não é um problema.